# github server-side git hooks (i.e. pre-commit and post-commit)

Tags: git, github, githooks, github-enterprise

I've looked around the answers on SO, and the web, and I can't see anything on how to set up a server-side git hook on github (as opposed to webhooks). Is there a way to do this?

Or alternatively, is there a way to set it up so that .git/hooks is a symlink to a part of the working tree *at the time of cloning*?

I should add that this is an internally-hosted github server.

Answer (score 34):

For *obvious* reasons, GitHub won’t allow you to execute arbitrary code on their servers as part of Git hooks. The only hooking they allow is through their webhooks or the integrated third-party services.

If you need to run some custom code, you will have to host that somewhere and set up a webhook to run it on *your own* server.

Comment: OK, but what if I have my own github server? And what about changing .git/hooks in the repo?

Comment: You mean GitHub Enterprise? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188798/githubenterprise-post-receive-hook).

Comment: I mean I wouldn't say it's obvious but definitely good to know.

Comment: It's not obvious particularly given that GitHub Actions allows arbitrary code executions. The difference is Actions run within VMs. There's no reason why server-side hooks couldn't be run within containers or k8s pods. I would say it's GitHub's decision not to support this.

Comment: It's _obvious_ the answer was not _obvious_ as it is now (7 years later) wrong. Even then though virtualization was already ubiquitous so the question was very reasonable and the not obvious.