# How to reject git push based on some rule

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

In our repository, we have instructed all developers not include one keyword (which is ops$abc) prefixed database objects. For example for "update ops$abc.tablename ." we have instructed to use update tablenane .

But developers are making this kind of mistake. Is there any way to reject push to the branch having this kind of code?

Comment: Must it be during `git push` ? Or are you also open to blocking it on `commit` ? Because this might help: [Git hook to reject commits where files contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26835998/2745495).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GitHub protected branches](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches):

1. Set your `master` or `release` branch as protected.
2. Add an automated test that fails if developers use `update ops$abc.tablename`.
3. Configure your CI server to run the automated tests when a GitHub pull request is opened.

Now developers won't be able to merge pull requests (or commit directly to the protected branch) with this change.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [git hooks](https://githooks.com/) feature to achieve this. BUT, it requires each developer to setup the `./.git/hooks/pre-commit` manually. Or you could create a shell script for developers in the repository to copy a `pre-commit` file into `./.git/hooks`.

No matter what, it requires developers cooperation.

Comment: Maybe better to use a server side `pre-receive` hook. That way, hook would execute even if someone is trying to push without having a `pre-commit`/`pre-push` hook in their local repo.

Comment: @Alderath, you are right. However, if the git repo is hosted in GitHub.com, GitLab.com or most of the public repo host services, [they won't allow server-side hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100581/github-server-side-git-hooks-i-e-pre-commit-and-post-commit).