# How to lock git repos master branch?

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit-hook

I need to lock master branch of a git repo. I tried pre-commit hooks but they are only client side hooks, but I want to lock master branch from most of the users. Can anyone tell me the steps for pre-receive hook on git ( I use github) or any better way to lock master?

PS: gitolite is not supported on our licensed version of github.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to lock a branch in GIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471340/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: since master is a branch too this seems like a dupe of the other.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant The solutions provided there wont work for me because: gitolite is not supported on our version of github. pre-commit hook is a client side hook(cant request every user to add this hook).whereas I am looking for a server-side hook.

Answer (score 2):

Licensed GitHub means "[GitHub`:enterprise`](https://enterprise.github.com/)", and that also means, as explained in the article "[Migrating from GitHub:FI](https://support.enterprise.github.com/entries/21179373-migrating-from-github-fi)": **no custom hooks allowed**.
(See also "[How can I add a custom git hook to a GitHub Enterprise repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385076/how-can-i-add-a-custom-git-hook-to-a-github-enterprise-repo)")

So I would approach this differently, and maintain not one repo on that server, but two repos (the second being a clone of the first).

Everyone can push to the first one, but only a selected user can push to the second one, which allows him/her to select from the first repo what is eligible to be pushed to the second.
So the '`repo2`' represents your '`master`' in a way, while '`repo1`' represents any other branch that all the other users can push to.
This is a bit similar to this [GitHub gist article](https://gist.github.com/3159952).

> **I suggest separating the release engineering team into their own organization**.
>   The developers will have to fork all of the repositories residing in the release engineering team.
>   The developers will be able to commit to `master` within their organization.
>   They must send pull requests in order to get their commits into the `release_engineering` organizations.
>
> Note: It will take some time to convince the customer that committing to the `master` branch of `acme_developers/foobar` is distinct from committing to the `master` branch of `acme_release_engineering/fooba`.

Comment: Thank you, further speaking to experts also suggested the same simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is probably to clone and host the repository on gitolite or some other system that supports branch locking, and setup a post-commit hook to mirror to your current github repository if you intend to keep that around. We are currently doing just that with a github clone.